# Docker-compose running container

Tags: package, docker, apache-zookeeper, docker-compose

I am trying to launch a zookeeper instance and a process which connects to the zookeeper instance using docker-compose (contents in docker-compose.yml file) . As soon as docker fetches the repositories for both the entities and launches the zookeeper instance, it fails to connect the process to the zookeeper instance and gracefully stops the entire set up throwing this error -

```
{
abc_1 |    "warnings" : [],
abc_1|    "diskperms" : {},
abc_1 |    "diskspace" : {},
abc_1 |    "data" : [],
abc_1 |    "log" : [
abc_1 |       "[ERROR] [28] Local-disk package '/packages/xyz.tar.gz' does not exist on disk."
abc_1 |    ],
abc_1 |    "http_info" : {},
abc_1 |    "result" : {
abc_1 |       "msg" : "Local-disk package '/packages/xyz.tar.gz' does not exist on disk.",
abc_1 |       "status" : 1
abc_1 |    },
abc_1 |    "state" : {}
abc_1 | }
dockerzookeeper1_abc_1 exited with code 1
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping dockerzookeeper1_zookeeper_1...
```

Could someone tell me how to resolve this issue with docker-compose ?

Dockerfile -

The docker file looks like this -

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre-headless wget
RUN wget -q -O - http://apache.mirrors.pair.com/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/zookeeper-3.4.6.tar.gz | tar -xzf - -C /opt \
    && mv /opt/zookeeper-3.4.6 /opt/zookeeper \
    && cp /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo_sample.cfg /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
EXPOSE 2181 2888 3888
WORKDIR /opt/zookeeper

VOLUME ["/opt/zookeeper/conf", "/tmp/zookeeper"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh"]
CMD ["start-foreground"
```

Comment: Is this still an issue? Can you provide the DockerFile and/or point to the image you're trying to run, also your docker-compose.yml file in order to have more info about the error?

Comment: Yes, this is still an issue.  Pasted the docker file above. docker-compose.yml just has this content - 

zookeeper:
  image: <path>
xyz:
 image : <path>
 links:
   - zookeeper

Comment: The Dockerfile misses the from at the top, is this an image you created? have you tried any other?

Comment: oh actually, i did have the "From" , the image is built successfully. Iforgot to paste that part. Just added the "From debian:jessie" statement, but that's not the issue.

Comment: Your output includes an error message (`Local-disk package '/packages/xyz.tar.gz' does not exist on disk`).  What is generating this message? What is "xyz.tar.gz"?

Comment: xyz is the docker image published on a repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by just restarting by boot2docker. The problem was with the DNS where i was switching between the connections between two places and luckily just restarting the boot2docker resolved this issue.